# Searching for overlapping integers in different indexes of tuples in a vector

Tags: c++, sorting, search, vector, tuples

I was wondering how one can search for overlaps in a vector of tuples.

For example, I have the `vector<tuple<int, int, int>> combo;`, and the elements of the vector is:

```
{10, 101, 1},
{10, 102, 2},
{12, 102, 3},
{14, 90, 4},
{1, 10, 101},
{2, 10, 102},
{3, 12, 102},
{4, 14, 90},
{101, 1, 10},
{102, 2, 10},
{102, 3, 12},
{90, 4, 14}
```

Here, you can tell that the bottom 8 tuples are just repeats of the first 4, except the integers are reordered in a different way. I want to find the non-overlapping combinations of the elements, not the *permutations* of the elements.

If the 1st index of the tuple is called **left**, second if called **middle**, and third is called **right**, then in other words, left, middle, and right can overlap with itself, but not with the other 2 indexes.

Comment: A naive approach would be to sort each tuple and eliminate exact duplicates. Dunno if sorting would be viable or if that would not be performant enough.

Comment: What does "overlap" mean? In my view `1-10-101` overlaps `2-10-102`.  If it's supposed to be left, middle and right, then the first tuple makes no sense, `101` is not the middle. Should they all be sorted? Do you want to eliminate all values that are permutations of a previous value? You have to be much more precise what the expected result should be. Your questions made sense up to "*I want to find the non-overlapping combinations...*"

Answer (score 0):

Convert the elements to a canonical representation. This allows you use a set data structure or similar to identify duplicates.

I'm assuming here you're trying to find permutations that do not result in one of the elements remaining in place, i.e. for values `{ a, b, c}` the matching permutations would be

```
{ a, b, c }
{ b, c, a }
{ c, a, b }
```

Furthermore I'm assuming even if multiple values are the same, they could be considered as listed in any order, i.e. `{ 1, 1, 2 }` would match `{ 1, 2, 1 }` even though the first element remains equal, since we could consider the first element to be the second one in the original.

This allows us use the lexicographically minimal alternative that as the canonical representation.

The following code uses `std::array<int, 3>` for convenience.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using ValueType = std::array<int, 3>;

constexpr ValueType ToCanonical(ValueType const& original)
{
    ValueType p1{ original[1], original[2], original[0] };
    ValueType p2 { original[2], original[0], original[1] };

    return (std::min)({ original, p1, p2 });
}

int main(void) {
    std::vector<ValueType> const values
    {
        {10, 101, 1},
        {10, 102, 2},
        {12, 102, 3},
        {14, 90, 4},
        {1, 10, 101},
        {2, 10, 102},
        {3, 12, 102},
        {4, 14, 90},
        {101, 1, 10},
        {102, 2, 10},
        {102, 3, 12},
        //{90, 4, 14},
        //{10, 101, 1},
        //{101, 10, 1},
        //{10, 1, 101},
        //{1, 101, 10},
        //{1, 1, 2},
        //{1, 2, 1},
        //{2, 1, 1},
    };


    std::map<ValueType, size_t> indices;

    for (size_t i = 0; i != values.size(); ++i)
    {
        auto insertResult = indices.try_emplace(ToCanonical(values[i]), i);
        if (!insertResult.second)
        {
            std::cout << "The element at index " << i << " is a duplicate of the element at index " << insertResult.first->second << '\n';
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```